# How to escape json with php to be parsed with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this php code which dynamically builds a JSON string and writes to a javascript string:

```
<?
    $s = json_encode(array("id" => "1", "name" => 'myn"ame'));  
?>
<script>
    <?echo ("var js = '".$s."';");?>
    var obj = $.parseJSON( js );
</script>
```

the JSON string looks just fine (" appears to be escaped ok):

```
    var js = '{"id":"1","name":"myn\"ame"}';
```

but $.parsesJSON is failing, it seems to want:

```
    var js = '{"id":"1","name":"myn\\"ame"}';
```

So how should I properly be escaping for this scenario?   (obviously I'd like to cater for all control characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode` will escape a PHP string into a JavaScript string.

```
<?php
    $json = json_encode(array("id" => "1", "name" => 'myn"ame'));
    $js_string = json_encode($json);
?>
<script>
    var json = <?php echo $js_string; ?>;
    var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
</script>
```

But it is pointless generating a string of JSON when you can use raw JSON as a JavaScript literal in the first place.

```
<?php
     $json = json_encode(array("id" => "1", "name" => 'myn"ame'));
?>
<script>
    var obj = <?php echo $json; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that json_encode could be used directly as a js string literal.

Comment: JSON = JavaScript Object Notation :)